# Create Category Product in a row inside ListView / GridView

Tags: layout, flutter, rows, flutter-layout

I want make a search column and its search icon beside the search column.
and below them there are some categories.

I want to make it like the following example.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2UHp.jpg

and I dont know the code how to make 2 boxes like my SS above.

but the result is like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHSqz.jpg

```
body: ListView (
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Search",
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)))),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset('images/Otomotif.png'),
              Image.asset('images/user.png'),
              Image.asset('images/returnbarang.png'),
              Image.asset('images/Vouchersaya.png')
            ],
          ),
          Text('PRODUK TERLARIS'),
           ],
          )
        ]
      )
```

hope you gaes could help me find the solution. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 ListView (
    children: <Widget>[
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Search",
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)))),
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset('images/Otomotif.png'),
          Image.asset('images/user.png'),
          Image.asset('images/returnbarang.png'),
          Image.asset('images/Vouchersaya.png')
        ],
      ),
      Text('PRODUK TERLARIS'),
       Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          items(),
          items()
        ],
      ),


       ],
      )
    ]
  )


items(){
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
      width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 24 )  / 2,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 1),
      ),
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text("Title"),
        subtitle: Text("subtitle"),
        trailing: Image.asset("images/toy.png",height: 60,width: 60,),

      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: okay mr @Android Team. I'll try your code. wait I'll give a review ASAP.
but thank you so much for helping me.